# Find all subsets

Tags: c++

I already managed to make me of all the subsets but I do not know how to make their values add up and identify what I want. If someone could explain to me please.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n=3;
    int arr[]={1,2,3};
    int v;
    int count = pow(2,n);
    int acum=0;
    cout << "Enter a value: ";
    cin >> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if ((i & (1 << j)) != 0){
                cout << arr[j] << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You managed to output the values of the sub-set. What prevents you to sum them up and check whether the result matches your expected value?

Comment: `int count = pow(2, n);` -> `int count = 1 << n;` and no need for `#include <math.h>`. Btw. in C++, you should prefer `<cmath>` over `<math.h>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your problem domain, is it valid to assume that all of the elements will be positive integers?  If so, then you might want to consider using a "Dynamic Programming" (DP) solution (instead of the "Generate and Test" approach that you had begun).

The DP approach would solve your example as follows:

- The initial task was to identify a subset whose sum is `v`=5.
- DP makes one single pass through your `arr[]` data (my implementation's `for i` loop)

  - For the first element `arr[0]`, that addition term (`1`) is either *used* or *not used*.  If that `1` addition term is *not used*, then the problem `arr[]={1,2,3},v=5` recursively becomes the sub-problem `arr[]={2,3},v=5`.  But if that `1` term is *used*, then the problem `arr[]={1,2,3},v=5` recursively becomes the sub-problem `arr[]={2,3},v=4`.  We "memoize" this possibility by recording the used term (the `1` value) in memory at `term[4]` (`term[]` is a utility array that had been allocated for this very "DP memoization" purpose).
  - For the next element `arr[1]`, again that term (`2`) is either *used* or *not used*.  If that term is *used*, then the `v=5` problem becomes a `v=3` sub-problem, whereas the `v=4` problem (if it exists) becomes a `v=2` sub-problem.  Again, any such sub-problem is recorded via "memoization" (in the same `term[]` utility array).
  - Finally, this pattern repeats for the final `arr[2]` element.
- Once that single pass through `arr[]` is finished, the solution can be "back-traced" through the "memoization", by an iteration that starts at `term[0]`.

This is a C++ implementation of the DP approach:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n = 3;
    int arr[n] = {1, 2, 3}; // All elements must be positive

    int v;
    std::cout << "Enter a value: ";
    std::cin >> v;
    int* term = new int[v];
    for (int init = 0; init < v; init++) {
        term[init] = 0;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int before = 0; before < v; before++) {
            if (term[before] == 0) {
                int after = before + arr[i];
                // This tests the "(if it exists)" condition in my verbal description:
                if (after == v || (after < v && term[after] != 0)) {
                    // This assignment performs the "memoization":
                    term[before] = arr[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (term[0] == 0) {
        std::cout << "No such subset exists";
    }
    else {
        int partialSum = 0;
        while (partialSum < v) {
            std::cout << term[partialSum];
            partialSum += term[partialSum];
            if (partialSum < v) {
                std::cout << "+";
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "=" << v;
            }
        }
    }
    delete[] term;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of raw owning pointer (that you forget to `delete[]` BTW).

Comment: The choice of C-array (over `std::vector`) was made so that `term[]` would be consistent with existing code (the original poster's `arr[]`).Thanks for pointing out the forgotten `delete[]` statement, which has now been added.

Comment: In the next part ```int* term = new int[v]```, can't I just change it to ```term [ ]```? is that I have not yet given that, and I do not understand that part